# Join that executes a where clause on the first table before the join select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null

I have two tables I need to write a Select statement for and I am using a JOIN.

Some of the data in the first table has nulls, which causes the convert part to fail.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM Heading H 
JOIN IncidentSystem S ON H.VTKReportID = S.VTKReportID 
WHERE H.StartDate IS NOT NULL AND H.EndDate IS NOT NULL
AND convert(datetime, StartDate, 101) >= '9/19/2023' 
AND convert(datetime, EndDate, 101) <= '9/20/2023'
```

This still causes an arithmetic error when it hits the nulls that am trying to remove.

I guess the execution does not stop when it finds a null but still tries to convert it anyway.

Because the nulls are sporatic through the database, I can do a top 1 today and it works, but more than that and it does not. Yesterday it was working with the top 4. I suspect it just quits before hitting the first null and each day more data is put into the database so it is random as to how many I can get before hitting a null.

The StartDate and EndDate were configured as nvarchar(30) by the original designers. Thus the convert function.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Fix the table design and use a `date` type for a *date* - don't store dates as strings, they are not strings. aside, the `where not null` is redundant, just use `try_convert` and use an ISO formatted date.

Comment: See `TRY_CAST` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: A `NULL` *can't* cause an arithmetic error. Arithmetic involving a `NULL` results in `NULL`, *every single time*.

Comment: Don't tell me your date is a varchar?

Comment: `null`s don't cause arithmetic or conversion errors. Probably `StartDate` or `EndDate` contain non-null non-date strings, such as empty strings or `'foo bar baz'`. Have you considered using `try_cast()` or `try_convert()` instead?

Comment: You *have* to use `TRY_CONVERT`. SQL does not guarantee the order of `WHERE` clauses, *even* if you use a subquery. The *only* way to guarantee no errors is to use `TRY_....` or `CASE`.

Comment: As recommended by others. fix your data. Make the datatype a `datetime` or a `date` and change any non-date values to NULL

Comment: So, this system is one that has been in place for over a decade.  It has over 496k entries and the vendor (and source code) is not around anymore.  So I would love to change the table design, but that is not an option.  I will try the try_convert as you all have suggested when I get back to work tomorrow.  Thank you so much, and ithey are a nvarchar(30) for the startdate and enddate.

Comment: I wonder why nvarchar(30) was chosen? A "date" is 8-10 characters and I'm unaware of requiring unicode to store dates, so every date string is using double the required storage, and the optimizer will be estimating approximately 30 bytes returned for each column per row for memory requirements; a pretty crummy design all-round!